# Dependency Injected UserManager is disposing on async call (ASP.NET CORE)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Core with its inbuilt dependency injection and asp.net identity.

The problem I am having is whenever I try and access any of the context's via async (ie in this example `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`) it is being disposed when accessing.

For example, my controller is below (The object we are concerned with is `UserManager`)

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
private readonly ViewRender _view;
private readonly IConfiguration _config;

public UserController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    ViewRender view,
    IConfiguration config)
{
    this._dbContext = dbContext;
    this._userManager = userManager;
    this._view = view;
    this._config = config;
}
```

Notice the `_userManager` is being injected using the visual studio template default setting in startup.cs

Now in a method in this controller I try the following:

```
[HttpDelete]
public async void Delete(string id)
{

    var user = _userManager.Users.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    user.Deleted = true;
    var result= await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

}
```

but when the `await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user)` is hit, it calls a "the object is disposed" error. My understanding of async / await is that the execution will stop at await? Therefore the controller should not dispose `_userManager` object until its completed? (obviously this logic is wrong)

A solution which works is to not use a aysnc method and just call `_userManager.UpdateAsync(user).Result;`  but would like to understand aysnc/await

Comment: refactor the Delete action to be be `async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id) { ... return Ok(); }`

Comment: But in this particular case I dont want the method to return anything?

Comment: Then use `async Task` which translates to a void method

Comment: BTW, FirstOrDefault() has an overload that will take the filter in your where(). Allowing you to combine them in one method rather than chaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update action to have `Task` return type instead of `void`:

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task Delete(string id) {
    var user = _userManager.Users.Where(a => a.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    user.Deleted = true;
    var result= await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
}
```

For a better understanding of async/await read this article

[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)