# Getting SqlTransaction exceptions using Entity Framework with ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

At times (especially when opening the same webpage in multiple tabs) I receive one of the following exception while saving changes using Entity Framework on ASP.NET Core. Currently, I'm running locally on IIS Express (through Visual Studio 2017 debug).

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext:Error: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes.
System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.ZombieCheck()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit()
   ...

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext:Error: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Commit()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit()
   ...

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   ...
```

These exceptions are thrown when the `SaveChangesAsync()` method in the following code is called:

```
public async void Remove( int statementId )
{
    Statement statement = _data.Statements.FirstOrDefault( s => s.StatementId == statementId );
    if ( statement != null )
    {
        _data.Statements.Remove( statement );
        await _data.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

`_data` is the `ApplicationDbContext`, which as per the ASP Core documentation can be dependency injected in the controller (in this case in a custom intermediate repository class) and reused without wrapping in `using` each time as in the past. However, the errors seem to imply this is not working as it should ...

Comment: I thought I pinpointed the problem: my repository class was registered through `IServiceCollection` as `AddTransient()`, whereas this is the incorrect lifetime. It [should be `AddScoped()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection). Regardless, ... (some?) of the exceptions remain.

Comment: For now, these problems seem to be gone when using the non-async `SaveChanges()` (and `AddScoped`), but I have no clue why async shound influence this?

Comment: Now that I know this might be related to using async, I found the following: [Dependency Injected UserManager is disposing on async call (ASP.NET CORE)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41325518/590790)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It turned out I had forgotten to use `await` on my Async call to `SaveChangesAsync()`.

This seemed to cause occasional drops in the connection to the database and then error 3902 ("The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding...") would be thrown at the SQL Server level.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the Entity Framework connection is dropped, and this thus is an issue with the lifetime of `ApplicationDbContext`.

Ensure that your repository class (the one relying on `ApplicationDbContext` internally) [is registered in IServiceCollection as `AddScoped()` and not `AddTransient()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection):

> Entity Framework contexts should be added to the services container
>   using the `Scoped` lifetime.

In addition, [use `async Task` instead of `async void` for asynchronous methods which do not return anything](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx):

> Async methods returning void don’t provide an easy way to notify the
>   calling code that they’ve completed.

It seems like `void` causes the called object to instantly be disposed (thus closing the connection) as there is nothing to wait for.